# Ag-Grid Tooltip partially hidden when overflows small grid

Tags: tooltip, ag-grid, hidden

Ag-Grid tooltip is partially hidden when it overflows the grid.

[image: part of the tooltip exceeeding grid boundaries is hidden]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS:

```css
.ag-popup .ag-popup-child {
    max-height: initial;
}
```

This will allow the popup to overflow.

However I found that the built in tooltip doesn't handle overflowing the viewport so you will end up with a different problem. I ended up having to integrate `popperjs` which does properly support repositioning a popup to prevent overflow of the viewport.

Comment: It does not seem to affect in any way.
Actually, I don't understand how line heght might affect overflow.

Comment: Sorry that was a cut and paste error on my part. Have amended answer.

Comment: I still cannot appreciate any effect. Are you sure this applies to agrid tooltip?